# How to find quantile of a row in PySpark dataframe?

Tags: dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, quantile

I have the following PySpark dataframe and I want to find percentile row-wise.

```
value   col_a     col_b  col_c
row_a   5.0        0.0   11.0
row_b   3394.0     0.0   4543.0
row_c   136111.0   0.0   219255.0
row_d   0.0        0.0   0.0
row_e   0.0        0.0   0.0
row_f   42.0       0.0   54.0
```

I want to add a new column in the main dataframe like below.

```
value   col_a     col_b  col_c      25%
row_a   5.0        0.0   11.0        2.5
row_b   3394.0     0.0   4543.0      1697
row_c   136111.0   0.0   219255.0    68055
row_d   0.0        0.0   0.0         0.0
row_e   0.0        0.0   0.0         0.0
row_f   42.0       0.0   54.0        21.0
```

In pandas, I could use this:

```py
df['25%']=df.quantile(0.25,axis=1)
```

Comment: You could check the revised answer

Answer (score 0):

You could do it utilizing Spark's `pandas_udf` - vectorized (well-performing) UDF version.

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
import pandas as pd

@F.pandas_udf('double')
def quantile(q: pd.Series, s: pd.DataFrame) -> pd.Series:
    return s.quantile(q[0], axis=1)
```

Test:

```py
df = spark.createDataFrame(
    [('row_a', 5.0, 0.0, 11.0),
     ('row_b', 3394.0, 0.0, 4543.0),
     ('row_c', 136111.0, 0.0, 219255.0),
     ('row_d', 0.0, 0.0, 0.0),
     ('row_e', 0.0, 0.0, 0.0),
     ('row_f', 42.0, 0.0, 54.0)],
    ['value', 'col_a', 'col_b', 'col_c']
)

df = df.withColumn('25%', quantile(F.lit(0.25), F.struct('col_a', 'col_b', 'col_c')))

df.show()
df.explain()
# +-----+--------+-----+--------+-------+
# |value|   col_a|col_b|   col_c|    25%|
# +-----+--------+-----+--------+-------+
# |row_a|     5.0|  0.0|    11.0|    2.5|
# |row_b|  3394.0|  0.0|  4543.0| 1697.0|
# |row_c|136111.0|  0.0|219255.0|68055.5|
# |row_d|     0.0|  0.0|     0.0|    0.0|
# |row_e|     0.0|  0.0|     0.0|    0.0|
# |row_f|    42.0|  0.0|    54.0|   21.0|
# +-----+--------+-----+--------+-------+
#
# == Physical Plan ==
# *(2) Project [value#526, col_a#527, col_b#528, col_c#529, pythonUDF0#563 AS 25%#535]
# +- ArrowEvalPython [quantile(0.25, struct(col_a, col_a#527, col_b, col_b#528, col_c, col_c#529))], [pythonUDF0#563], 200
#    +- *(1) Scan ExistingRDD[value#526,col_a#527,col_b#528,col_c#529]
```

<sup>[Inspiration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71750833/create-column-using-spark-pandas-udf-with-dynamic-number-of-input-columns#71808298)</sup>

---

Or create `quantile` function from scratch (no UDF of any type).

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
import math

def quantile(q, *cols):
    if q < 0 or q > 1:
        raise ValueError("Parameter q should be 0 <= q <= 1")

    if not cols:
        raise ValueError("List of columns should be provided")

    idx = (len(cols) - 1) * q
    i = math.floor(idx)
    j = math.ceil(idx)
    fraction = idx - i

    arr = F.array_sort(F.array(*cols))

    return arr.getItem(i) + (arr.getItem(j) - arr.getItem(i)) * fraction
```

```py
df = spark.createDataFrame(
    [('row_a', 5.0, 0.0, 11.0),
     ('row_b', 3394.0, 0.0, 4543.0),
     ('row_c', 136111.0, 0.0, 219255.0),
     ('row_d', 0.0, 0.0, 0.0),
     ('row_e', 0.0, 0.0, 0.0),
     ('row_f', 42.0, 0.0, 54.0)],
    ['value', 'col_a', 'col_b', 'col_c']
)

df = df.withColumn('0.25%', quantile(0.25, 'col_a', 'col_b', 'col_c'))

df.show()
df.explain()
# +-----+--------+-----+--------+-------+
# |value|   col_a|col_b|   col_c|  0.25%|
# +-----+--------+-----+--------+-------+
# |row_a|     5.0|  0.0|    11.0|    2.5|
# |row_b|  3394.0|  0.0|  4543.0| 1697.0|
# |row_c|136111.0|  0.0|219255.0|68055.5|
# |row_d|     0.0|  0.0|     0.0|    0.0|
# |row_e|     0.0|  0.0|     0.0|    0.0|
# |row_f|    42.0|  0.0|    54.0|   21.0|
# +-----+--------+-----+--------+-------+

# == Physical Plan ==
# Project [value#564, col_a#565, col_b#566, col_c#567, (array_sort(array(col_a#565, col_b#566, col_c#567), lambdafunction(if ((isnull(lambda left#573) AND isnull(lambda right#574))) 0 else if (isnull(lambda left#573)) 1 else if (isnull(lambda right#574)) -1 else if ((lambda left#573 < lambda right#574)) -1 else if ((lambda left#573 > lambda right#574)) 1 else 0, lambda left#573, lambda right#574, false))[0] + ((array_sort(array(col_a#565, col_b#566, col_c#567), lambdafunction(if ((isnull(lambda left#575) AND isnull(lambda right#576))) 0 else if (isnull(lambda left#575)) 1 else if (isnull(lambda right#576)) -1 else if ((lambda left#575 < lambda right#576)) -1 else if ((lambda left#575 > lambda right#576)) 1 else 0, lambda left#575, lambda right#576, false))[1] - array_sort(array(col_a#565, col_b#566, col_c#567), lambdafunction(if ((isnull(lambda left#577) AND isnull(lambda right#578))) 0 else if (isnull(lambda left#577)) 1 else if (isnull(lambda right#578)) -1 else if ((lambda left#577 < lambda right#578)) -1 else if ((lambda left#577 > lambda right#578)) 1 else 0, lambda left#577, lambda right#578, false))[0]) * 0.5)) AS 0.25%#572]
# +- *(1) Scan ExistingRDD[value#564,col_a#565,col_b#566,col_c#567]
```

<sup>[Inspiration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71750833/create-column-using-spark-pandas-udf-with-dynamic-number-of-input-columns#71856466)</sup>